# How to set height to wrap text only in certain screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a TD which I set fixed height:

```
 <td class="col span_2_of_3 span_pad_left vertAlignT setDim hidOverflow">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>                            
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.setDim {
    min-height: 115px;
    max-height: 115px;
}
```

How can I set the default height to only wrap around the text and not set fixed height when it is less than 715px.

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
@media (max-width: 715px) {
    .setDim {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 715px) {
    .setDim {
        min-height: inherit;
        max-height: inherit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `0` makes the content disappear :/